# PDFQuery - 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013'

Tags: python, pdf, pdfminer

I am using [PDFQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfquery) to extract data from PDF. It was working fine for most of the PDFs.

Recently for few PDFs I am getting the following errors on a couple of pages:

```
'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 91: ordinal not in range(128)

'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

My code looks like this:

```
pdf = pdfquery.PDFQuery(pdf_file)
pages_in_pdf = pdf.doc.catalog['Pages'].resolve()['Count']
for i in range(0, pages_in_pdf):

try:
    pdf.load(i)
    # logic
except ValueError as e:
    print('Error on page number {0}. Error message is {1}'.format(i, e))
```

Comment: You are trying to encode unicode to ascii

Comment: ascii is a subset of unicode, not everything in unicode exists in ascii

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I narrowd the issue to this line `value = pdf.pq('LTTextLineHorizontal:in_bbox("%s, %s, %s, %s")' % (
            left_corner, bottom_corner - 20, right_corner + 200, top_corner)).text()`. `print(value)` was throwing exception. Changing it to `print(value.encode('ascii', 'ignore')` fixed it. Is there a better way to do this? Or do I need to encode all values extracted from PDF?